# Jenkins/Hudson call script on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, hudson, playframework-1.x

Today, on my work, when we need to deploy a Play! Framework (1.2.7) app in our EC2 Instance (AWS), we need to access the server and call a script that download all the source code, precompile the source code, start Play! Framework and restart nginx (everything in one script - .sh).

This process work fine today, but in emergency cases it's very slowly because we need to access de EC2 Instance (with key pair) and depending on the location the internet is slowly.

I want to know if is possible to use Hudson/Jenkins to just call this script on my EC2 Instances. I know that Hudson/Jenkins have a lot of functionality (test, build, etc.) but for now I just want to deploy my app (call the script from ec2-instance).

If anyone knows another tool that help, I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What build tool are you using? sbt, ant, maven, gradle ... could do this.

Comment: I'm using SBT (comes with Play! Framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can use/build SBT plugins to run the remote command, or simply exec the local ssh with the command, but that can get quite hard to debug.

If you can build your instance to bootstrap itself from scratch, for example with a [UserData script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), then all you need to do is terminate your old instance and start a new one, and that is much easier to automate.